# Assembly procedures called and defined in C code

Tags: c, assembly, gcc

I have the following assembly code:

```
global stuff
    
       stuff:
            ;do stuff
```

I wish to call this from C code, so would it be able to be called from a C program which contains it in `_asm()`?

Comment: Why not just inline it in C?

Comment: Im writing an OS, and its basically writing byte x to port y.

Comment: So, again, why not just inline it? This is what the Linux Kernel does.

Comment: Have you used a [reference like this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/Mixed_C_and_Assembly_Programming) as a baseline?

Comment: You, you can use `asm(".globl stuff\n"  "stuff:\n" "...");` at global scope, but normally it's better to define pure asm functions in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Just because Linux does it is not a reason to do something.  I am baffled by the use/desire to use inline assembly, but yes, sure, there are ways to do this which you could easily figure out.  If you are asking this you are not quite ready to write an operating system.  Keep working on it though. You need C and tool basics before you begin.  An operating system is essentially a big bare-metal program.

If you tagged this nasm then you are not interested in inline asm anyway, just use real asm gas or nasm.

This

```
int fun ( void )
{
    return 5;
}
```

does/can become:

```
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   b8 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%eax
   5:   c3
```

so that means I can do this

```
.globl fun
fun:
    mov $0x5,%eax
    retq
```

and this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun ( void );
int main ( void )
{
    printf("%d\n",fun());
    return 0;
}
```

and build a binary linking the two parts which prints 5 when run.

So then with nasm I can

```
global fun
fun:
    mov eax,5
    ret
```

confirming it is the same machine code in this case or at least an equivalent.

```
0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   b8 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%eax
   5:   c3                      retq
```

so I can link that in instead and it prints 5 as well.

So now I can do a simple inline, very real asm like, perhaps what you were asking

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun ( void );
asm(".globl fun ; fun: mov $0x5,%eax ; retq");
int main ( void )
{
    printf("%d\n",fun());
    return 0;
}
```

This was using gcc, inline asm is tool specific and not assumed to be portable.

And now you can grossly over complicate it from there.

Using an abstraction to perform I/O operations ("its basically writing byte x to port y") in an OS (or anywhere) is absolutely the right thing to do (you do not want to inline something like that), so a separate function be it real asm or C or some hybrid is a good idea worth pursuing.   At the end of the day though for an access type function like that you need to be in complete control over the instruction used so however you choose to do that is up to you.  But elementary use of tools and the language is a required before starting any kind of work like this.  You can examine different operating systems that exist now as a reference, but this is yours not theirs, your personal preferences not someone else's, your knowledge of the language and tools and assumptions not someone else's.  They may have a system level implementation of something that you may not see all of and can fall into traps by simply copying a piece here or there.

Comment: im sorry for the tag problem, this is my very first post.

Comment: i just removed the tag

Comment: how would i pass parameters to fun()?

Comment: fun() in this example takes no parameters, if it did, parameters are usually passed using the stack (with the (intel syntax) `push` and `pop` instructions)